# MVC Redirection in OnAuthorization causes authorization to fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I'm trying to redirect the user to a different action if their email address has not been validated. The thing is, I don't want them to be logged out, I just want to redirect them. When I do this in OnAuthorization for the controller, it redirects as expected, but the user is not authenticated. I'm not sure why this is. My code looks like this:

```
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        //_applicationService.CurrentUser is populated correctly at this point
        // from Controller.User
        if (_applicationService.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            if (_applicationService.CurrentUser.EmailVerified != true)
            {
                var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
                var verifyEmailUrl = url.Action("EmailVerificationRequired", "Account", null);
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(verifyEmailUrl);
            }
        }

    }
```

Note: I've removed unnecessary code to make it clearer. _applicationService.CurrentUser is populated with the current user - and the user has been authenticated correctly when it gets to that point. But after the redirect the user is no longer authenticated.

How can I achieve this redirect without affecting the built in user authorization?

I've tried putting my code into OnActionExecuting, and I've also tried implementing it in a custom ActionFilterAttribute as well, but wherever I put this redirect in it prevents the 'User' (ie: System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal Controller.User) from getting authenticated.

What am I missing here? Hope this makes sense. Any help much appreciated.

In response to Darin's request for my login action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        string errorMessage = "The username or password is incorrect";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_contextExecutor.ExecuteContextForModel<LoginContextModel, bool>(new LoginContextModel(){                    
              LoginViewModel = model  
            }))
            {
                ViewBag.CurrentUser = _applicationService.CurrentUser;
                _formsAuthenticationService.SetAuthCookie(model.LoginEmailAddress, model.RememberMe);

                if (_applicationService.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home").Success("Thank you for logging in.");
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage = "Email address not found or invalid password.";
            }
        }

        return View(model).Error(errorMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Could you show how are you authenticating the user - your `LogOn` action?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I've added my login action as requested.

Comment: This is just what I've been looking for!  Saved a lot of time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I've now found where I was going wrong. The problem was that I was being a bit of a goon and I didn't fully understand what was happening when I was doing:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(verifyEmailUrl);
```

I didn't realise that I am actually starting a new request with this, I mistakenly thought that I was just redirecting to another action. It seems obvious now that this will be a new request.

So, the problem was that my `EmailVerificationRequired` action was not authorizing the user, and thus when it got to this action the current user was null. So the fix was add the authorization to that action and now it's all fine.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in your login actionresult. Try placing the

```
        if (_applicationService.CurrentUser.EmailVerified != true)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("EmailVerificationRequired", "Account"); 
        }
```

code immediately after this line:

```
_formsAuthenticationService.SetAuthCookie(model.LoginEmailAddress, model.RememberMe);
```

Next, set breakpoints and step through the Login action. If you do not reach the if (_applicationService.CurrentUser.EmailVerified != true) line then it indicates that your user is not authenticated, and you have a different problem to address.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The thing is, I want to check this every time any action which requires authentication is accessed. Otherwise a user who was logged in but who's email address had not been verified would still be able to access parts of the site by typing the URL in.That's why I wanted it in OnAuthorization, rather than just putting it in the login action.

Comment: @soupy1976 Based on your comment, I edited the code sample to prevent the user from accessing secure parts of the site without being both authenticated and having email verified. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks again for your help Tarzan. The problem with putting this check in the login action is that the user would still be able to access the content by typing the url into the browser (if they happened to know it or had it saved in their history or something). I need to do this check in the authorization during the actual page request, rather than just checking it as they log in otherwise there is barely any security at all.

Comment: @soupy1976, the "FormsAuthentication.SignOut();" line would prevent the user from being able to access other content by typing the url into the browser. Anyway, sounds like you found a good solution with another approach. Cheers.